# How can I Identify a line in a csv file based on a variable value and start iterating over the file lines from that line onwards in Groovy?

Tags: csv, groovy, jmeter

I am using Jmeter to send multiple HTTPS requests to some API. I need to compose the XML body of these requests with different data each time.

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
iDocType,iDocId,iName,iDate
P,555551555,Braiden,2022-12-31
I,100000001,Dominique,2024-12-10
P,100000002,Joyce,2025-11-15
.........
```

And I have this piece of code in a JSR223 PreProcessor (under the HTTPS Sampler) which creates multiple XML objects and populates them one by one with csv values and finally gives this object to Jmeter to use in the sampler as request body data:

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
def pReqID = 'ID0000'

def numberOfNodes = 3

//input from csv file
travelDocNbr = vars.get('iDocId').toInteger();

def lines = new File("TestData\\test.csv").readLines()

xml.nodes() {
    1.upto(numberOfNodes, { lineNo ->
        xml.object(a: 'false', b: 'false', pReqID: pReqID + (lineNo).toString()) {
            xml.al(ad: '2021-09-20', alc: 'bla', bla: '2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z', sn: 'AB8912')
            xml.doc(docType: lines.get(lineNo).split(',')[0],
                    docId: lines.get(lineNo).split(',')[1],
                    name: lines.get(lineNo).split(',')[2],
                    date: lines.get(lineNo).split(',')[3])
            }
        }
    )
}

def nodeAsText = writer.toString()
//log.info(nodeAsText)

vars.put('passengers3XmlObj', nodeAsText)
```

This always gives this result:

```
<nodes>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00001'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='555551555' name='Braiden' date='12/31/2022' />
  </object>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00002'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='100000001' name='Dominique' date='12/10/2024' />
  </object>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00003'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='100000002' name='Joyce' date='11/15/2025' />
  </object>
</nodes>
```

The problem is that this script starts composing objects from the first value in the CSV file and always creates the same XML object in each sampler request's body.
I need it to change values from the CSV each time. For this, I was thinking if I could have a variable which always changes in each sampler iteration, like the iName value (I get a different one on each sampler iteration thanks to the CSV Data Set config test element) and use that to find the line in the CSV file and start composing objects from that line onwards.

So, for example, given that the csv file has just the 3 lines mentioned at the beginning and I have the value "Dominique" stored in a variable I want to pass it to a function and get the following result:

```
<nodes>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00001'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='100000001' name='Dominique' date='12/10/2024' />
  </object>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00002'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='100000002' name='Joyce' date='11/15/2025' />
  </object>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00003'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='555551555' name='Braiden' date='12/31/2022' />
  </object>
</nodes>
```

Can someone please tell me how this can be done?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @injecteer, I ended up with this code which, in my implementation, does not work as intended :

```
def pReqID = 'ID0000'

def numberOfNodes = 10
String startFrom = 'Dominique'

int pos = -1

// @injecteer
def text = new File("TestData\\\validTravellerDocuments.csv").text

// @injecteer
def csv = text.readLines().drop( 1 ).withIndex().collect{
  def ( docType, docId, name, date ) = it[ 0 ].trim().split( ',' )
  if( -1 == pos && startFrom == name ) pos = it[ 1 ]
  [ docType:docType, docId:docId, name:name, date:date ]
}

//here the skipped lines are reodered to the bottom, if needed
def reoderedCsv = -1 < pos ? csv[ pos..-1 ] + csv[ 0..<pos ] : csv
log.info reoderedCsv

def writer = new StringWriter()
new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer).nodes() {

    reoderedCsv.take numberOfNodes eachWithIndex{ data, ix ->
         object(a: 'false', b: 'false', pReqID:"$pReqID${ix + 1}" ) {
            al ad:'2021-09-20', alc:'bla', bla:'2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z', sn:'AB8912'
            doc data
         }
         log.info "$data -> ${data.getClass()}"
    }
}


def nodesAsText = writer.toString()
log.info(nodesAsText)
```

The current problem is that the  section gets populated in this manner:
If I ask for 10 nodes, I get a behavior like this:

```
<doc>D</doc>
... 
<doc>o</doc> 
... 
<doc>c</doc> 
...
<doc>T</doc> 
...
<doc>y</doc>
... 
<doc>p</doc>
...
<doc>e</doc> 
...
<doc>,</doc>
etc...
```

Comment: I tried hard to understand your problem and failed. Provide the current and desired outputs

Comment: @injecteer Thanks for the feedback. I updated the question. Hoping it makes more sense now.

Comment: I see. I updated the "misbehaving" lines in your question and marked them with `// @injecteer`

Comment: @injecteer Thanks a lot! it works now! I had to comment the log statements because they were trying to print ArrayList and log.info() is only applicable for String argument types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the code in a natural groovy way.

UPDATE:
I added some more CSV lines to demonstrate how `numberOfNodes` affects the output.

```
def pReqID = 'ID0000'

def numberOfNodes = 2
String startFrom = 'Dominique'

int pos = -1

def csv = """\
iDocType,iDocId,iName,iDate
P,555551555,Braiden,2022-12-31 
I,100000001,Dominique,2024-12-10 
P,100000002,Joyce,2025-11-15
P,555551555,Braiden,2022-12-31 
I,100000001,Dominique,2024-12-10 
P,100000002,Joyce,2025-11-15
""".readLines().drop( 1 ).withIndex().collect{
  def ( docType, docId, name, date ) = it[ 0 ].trim().split( ',' )
  if( -1 == pos && startFrom == name ) pos = it[ 1 ]
  [ docType:docType, docId:docId, name:name, date:date ]
}

//here the skipped lines are reodered to the bottom, if needed
def reoderedCsv = -1 < pos ? csv[ pos..-1 ] + csv[ 0..<pos ] : csv

def writer = new StringWriter()
new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer).nodes() {

    reoderedCsv.take numberOfNodes eachWithIndex{ data, ix ->
         object(a: 'false', b: 'false', pReqID:"$pReqID${ix + 1}" ) {
            al ad:'2021-09-20', alc:'bla', bla:'2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z', sn:'AB8912'
            doc data
         }
    }
}

println writer
```

prints:

```
<nodes>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00001'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='I' docId='100000001' name='Dominique' date='2024-12-10' />
  </object>
  <object a='false' b='false' pReqID='ID00002'>
    <al ad='2021-09-20' alc='bla' bla='2021-09-20T11:00:00.000Z' sn='AB8912' />
    <doc docType='P' docId='100000002' name='Joyce' date='2025-11-15' />
  </object>
</nodes>
```

with `numberOfNodes = 3` and more the code print the desired output of yours

Comment: This is great, but how can I start from the top of the CSV file to create 3 or more objects inside if I get to the end of the file? I need to define how many <object></object> objects I need inside the <nodes> </nodes> tags. If I define a variable with number 3 or 99, and the file is is small in lines length, I need the iteration of the file to continue from the top of the file to the bottom again and again and keep composing <object></object> objects until the target number is reached.

Comment: see the update..

Comment: Sry for the late reply. This is pretty awesome coding! I tested the code and indeed it continues with the lines which are skipped from the file. I am trying to replace the csv which you hardcoded with a file and I am doing:
`def csv = new File("TestData\validTravellerDocuments.csv") 
csv.readLines()`
But I am getting an error:
`Script44.groovy: 8: Unexpected input: '"' @ line 8, column 20.
   def csv = new File("TestData\validTravellerDocuments.csv")`

Comment: sounds like you must use double slashes: `def csv = new File("TestData\\validTravellerDocuments.csv")`

Comment: Ok, so I it was with double backslashes, I wrote it with one in the comment, by mistake. That was the behavior for double backslashes. Now, if I add a third backslash:
`def csv = new File("TestData\\\validTravellerDocuments.csv")
csv.readLines().drop( 1 ).withIndex().collect{....}`
I get this error:
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (IntRange) values: [1..-1]
Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), getPath(), getText(), getName(), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), getText(java.lang.String)`

Comment: what happens if you omit `drop( 1 )`?

Comment: same thing, but indicating different values `No signature of method: java.io.File.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (IntRange) values: [2..-1]`

Comment: hmm it might be to jenkins limitations... try `new File('').text.readLines()`

Comment: That worked! The errors are gone now, it creates the objects, but the `<doc></doc>` section of each object just contains one letter. If I ask for 10 nodes, I get a behavior like this:
`<doc>D</doc>
...
<doc>o</doc>
...
<doc>c</doc>
<doc>T</doc>
<doc>y</doc>
<doc>p</doc>
<doc>e</doc>
...
<doc>,</doc>`
etc....

Comment: print `data` variable and its class out. Looks like you messed up somewhere, and the data is a String with`'docType'`

Comment: For `numberOfNodes = 10`, this is what `data` variable prints in the log on each iteration. I don't understand why, as I have not changed anything, except what we have discussed above.
`PreProcessor: D
PreProcessor: o
PreProcessor: c
PreProcessor: T
PreProcessor: y
PreProcessor: p
PreProcessor: e
PreProcessor: ,
PreProcessor: i
PreProcessor: D`
How do I print the class of `data` variable out?

Comment: `println "$data -> ${data.getClass()}`

Comment: In JMeter I am only able to print using log.info() and this needs to contain a string.
If I do `log.info("$data -> ${data.getClass()})` then I get this error:
`Script85.groovy: 30: token recognition error at: '\n' @ line 30, column 48.
   ("$data -> ${data.getClass()})` ;
I was able to do `log.info(data.getClass().toString())` thought and this prints `class java.lang.String`

Comment: you forgot the `"` at the end: `log.info "$data -> ${data.getClass()}"`

Comment: Aha, cool, thx. This is the outcome: 
`D -> class java.lang.String
o -> class java.lang.String
c -> class java.lang.String
T -> class java.lang.String
y -> class java.lang.String
p -> class java.lang.String
e -> class java.lang.String
, -> class java.lang.String
i -> class java.lang.String
D -> class java.lang.String`

Comment: the log shows, that the code `reoderedCsv.take numberOfNodes eachWithIndex{}` iterates over a String  of`"DocType,iD"`. This means that you are iterating NOT over `reoderedCsv` (which you should be), but rather over your original String-csv

Comment: I fail to understand the cause. I kept looking and the code is the same as you wrote it, with the only exception being at the beginning, in this part:
`def csv = new File("TestData\\\validTravellerDocuments.csv").text
csv.readLines()..........`

Comment: post the whole code in your original question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the number of line where `Dominique` text is present it can be done using [findIndexOf() function](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#findIndexOf(groovy.lang.Closure)) like:

```
def dominiquePosition = lines.findIndexOf { line -> line.contains('Dominique') }
```

then you can start building your XML from the position retrieved in the above line:

```
dominiquePosition.upto(numberOfNodes, { lineNo ->
```

The iteration can be obtained using `vars.getIteration()` function where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance. See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! This works, but I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException eventually when reaching the end of the CSV file. How can I mitigate this?
Also, you mentioned vars.getIteration() --> Why do you think that I need this ?